# Can Doxygen check the param "[in]" and "[out]" annotations?

Tags: doxygen

Consider the following snip with Doxygen tags:

```
/**
* \brief An example function
* \param[in]   a  Input parameter
* \param[out]  b  Output parameter
*/
void example(const int *a, int *b)
{
    // do something
}
```

Is it possible to configure Doxygen to spot a mismatch between the annotations and the function declaration?  For example if the documentation for parameter "a" is changed to:

```
\param[out]  a  Input parameter
```

...then can Doxygen issue a warning that a const pointer can't be an output parameter?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: At the best of my knowledge doxygen cannot, best would be to submit an enhancement request in Bugzilla.

Comment: It would be a nice feature!